# Reducing trace minimization to generalized eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, variational-analysis, generalized-eigenvector

I'm looking for insight in solving the following optimization over symmetric matrices A and positive-definite H.

$$R=\max_{A}\frac{\text{tr}(HA)^2+2\text{tr}(HAHA)}{\text{tr}(AHA)}$$

The [paper](https://www.di.ens.fr/~fbach/aistats_defossez_bach_with_supp.pdf) originally states that this reduces to generalized eigenvalue problem, can anyone see the conversion?

Using CAS I [can see](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/maximizing-quantities-of-trace.nb) the following sample solution

$$R=\frac{9+\sqrt{17}}{2}$$
for 
$$H=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 2\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Is H necessarily symmetric?

Comment: What is $S(R^d)$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo H is positive-definite, S(R^d) is symmetric matrices, edited

Comment: So, $R$ is a given algebraic number and $S(R^d)$ somehow is the set of symmetric matrices. I am still confused. What is $S$?

Comment: I agree that notation is confusing, I took it from the paper, edited the question to get rid of S(R^d)